# Why do my sshd logs show many tries on invalid ports?

Tags: ssh, logs, authentication

My ssh daemon is setup to listen on port 2221. I have also disabled root login from ssh.

I don't understand why in `auth.log` I see attempts to log on other ports (example with 4627 here).

```
May 17 15:36:04 srv01 sshd[21682]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
May 17 15:36:08 srv01 sshd[21706]: User root from 218.10.19.134 not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
May 17 15:36:08 srv01 sshd[21706]: input_userauth_request: invalid user root [preauth]
May 17 15:36:10 srv01 sshd[21706]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.10.19.134  user=root
May 17 15:36:12 srv01 sshd[21706]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.10.19.134 port 4627 ssh2
May 17 15:36:15 srv01 sshd[21706]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.10.19.134 port 4627 ssh2
May 17 15:36:17 srv01 sshd[21706]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.10.19.134 port 4627 ssh2
May 17 15:36:19 srv01 sshd[21706]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.10.19.134 port 4627 ssh2
May 17 15:36:24 srv01 sshd[21706]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.10.19.134 port 4627 ssh2
May 17 15:36:27 srv01 sshd[21706]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.10.19.134 port 4627 ssh2
May 17 15:36:27 srv01 sshd[21706]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for root [preauth]
```

SSHD is supposed to take these tries into account. Why do the logs say user/password is not matching whereas it shouldn't *receive* the request (wrong port)? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The logs tell you:

Someone with the IP `218.10.19.134` and from port `4627` was trying several times to login as user root with a password. **But:**

- user root is `invalid` anyway, the logs is just informing you of the login attempts
- the attempted login method was `password` authentication (not public key or anything else)
- the source port was `4627`, the destination port was `2221` (not written into the logs, as sshd is only listening to `2221`, any other attempts on other ports aren’t noticed by sshd)
- after some attempts, sshd blocked login by `disconnecting` the tcp connection

You’ll find all the highlighted words of my answer in your logs, except for the `2221`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will disable password authentication to deal with keys.

Answer (score 5):

The port number given in the log is the port on the client side, not on yours.